# How to fit a helix using `cftool` in Matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, curve-fitting, model-fitting

I am trying to fit some helical data to a helical parametric equation, so as to find the pitch, radius and angle with respect to the z-axis. 
If I use the cftool, this is what I am allowed to do in terms of customization (see pic below). There is no option for parametric equations, where the z data can be used as a time variable. Is there any way that this can be done? If not, what functions/tools/methods do you suggest?

[image: 1]]

Comment: As you noticed correctly, `cftool` cannot be used with parametric equations. You need to remember that this is just a tool that helps the user perform a certain mathematical operation. I would advise you to have courage and formulate this like a proper optimization problem, and in following use one of the existing tools for solving them, such as `fmincon` etc.

Comment: You might (I haven't tested it!) be able to find the parameters step by step using cftool. First, fit a line ibn 3D to the data, this will give you the rotation angle and translation. Then, take your data and re-rotate and re-tranlsate it. From this new data, fit `x(t)` and `y(t)` separately, which will give you the radii.